# how to update elements in a Map containing JsonNode in java?

Tags: java, json, jackson, fasterxml

Here is the `json`

```
{
    "UserInfoService": {
        "state": "active",
        "message": [
            "hello",
            "world"
        ]
    },
    "UserProfileService": {
        "state": "inactive",
        "message": "[foo,bar]"
    }
}
```

I have map which stores these jsonNode based on versions

eg:`{"v1": jsonNode@1343, "v2":jsonNOde@1353543}`

Here is my method:

```
public class ModifyMap {

   private Map<String,JsonNode> map = new HashMap<>();

    private void updateNode(Foobar foo,String version, List<String> messages, String mainKey){
        JsonNode rootNode = featureStatusNodes.get(version);
        if (featureNode==null){
            rootNode=mapper.createObjectNode();
        }
        JsonNode stateNode = mapper.convertValue(new Status(foo.getState()), JsonNode.class);
        JsonNode messageNode = mapper.convertValue(messages, JsonNode.class);
        ((ObjectNode) rootNode).set("state",stateNode);
        ((ObjectNode) rootNode).set("message",messageNode);
        rootNode.put(version, featureNode);
    }
}

public class Status {

    String state;
    //getters and setters

}

public class FooBar {

   Status status;

   //getters and setters

}
```

This is what I have.

but how would I set the `mainKey` that is passed in parameter as the top-level node. In the above example, the `mainKey` would be `userInfoService`.

The factors to consider are 
if `mainKey`node is present, then update it with passed values

if it is not present, then create one and update it.

Note that in the example there are two `mainKeys`: `userInfoService`, `userProfileService`.

There is a `top-level map` that maintains `versions` to `jsonNode` mapping.

In the above case, if for a given version, if jsonNode is null, create one and update it .

if for a given version, a jsonNode (eg `userInfoService`) is present but `userProfileService` is not present, then update the root to include the `userProfileService`.

If the update is needed only for `userInfoService` which is already present then update it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You need an extra level of JsonNode (or Map), to store the mainKey->node associations.

For example:

```
Map<String, Map<String, ObjectNode>> map = new HashMap<>();

private void updateNode(Foobar foo,
                        String version,
                        List<String> messages,
                        String mainKey) {
    Map<String, ObjectNode> versionedMap = map.computeIfAbsent(version, HashMap::new);
    ObjectNode rootNode = versionedMap.computeIfAbsent(mainKey, mapper::createObjectNode);
    // update rootNode
}
```

or:

```
Map<String, ObjectNode> map = new HashMap<>();

private void updateNode(Foobar foo,
                        String version,
                        List<String> messages,
                        String mainKey) {
    ObjectNode versionedNode = map.computeIfAbsent(version, mapper::createObjectNode);
    ObjectNode rootNode = versionedNode.get(mainKey);
    if (rootNode == null) {
        rootNode = mapper.createObjectNode();
        versionedNode.set(mainKey, rootNode);
    }
    // update rootNode
}
```